# Days and Months reversing when changing . (dot) for / (slash) with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently trying to automate the actualization of a report where the new info is downloaded from SAP, the problem arises when i try to change a column with dates with the format dd.mm.yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy/.

I'm not experienced in VBA, what i first try was to record what i would do in Excel, which is to select the whole column and replace (Ctrl+H) . for /
But when i run that Macro, the days < 13 are swaped for the months. I also try to code the replacing, but with no avail.

The column with dates is "E", and i only copy the informatio (no header).
The first thing i tried, recording a macro, returned,

```
Range("E9").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Replace What:=".", Replacement:="/", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

And then what i manually tried to code was,

```
    Columns("E").Replace What:="01.", Replacement:="1/", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    Columns("E").Replace What:="02.", Replacement:="2/", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    Columns("E").Replace What:="03.", Replacement:="3/", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    Columns("E").Replace What:="04.", Replacement:="4/", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    Columns("E").Replace What:="05.", Replacement:="5/", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    Columns("E").Replace What:="06.", Replacement:="6/", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    Columns("E").Replace What:="07.", Replacement:="7/", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    Columns("E").Replace What:="08.", Replacement:="8/", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    Columns("E").Replace What:="09.", Replacement:="9/", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    Columns("E").Replace What:="10.", Replacement:="10/", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    Columns("E").Replace What:="11.", Replacement:="11/", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    Columns("E").Replace What:="12.", Replacement:="12/", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    Columns("E").Replace What:="13.", Replacement:="13/", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    Columns("E").Replace What:="14.", Replacement:="14/", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    Columns("E").Replace What:="15.", Replacement:="15/", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    Columns("E").Replace What:="16.", Replacement:="16/", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    Columns("E").Replace What:="17.", Replacement:="17/", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    Columns("E").Replace What:="18.", Replacement:="18/", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    Columns("E").Replace What:="19.", Replacement:="19/", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    Columns("E").Replace What:="20.", Replacement:="20/", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    Columns("E").Replace What:="21.", Replacement:="21/", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    Columns("E").Replace What:="22.", Replacement:="22/", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    Columns("E").Replace What:="23.", Replacement:="23/", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    Columns("E").Replace What:="24.", Replacement:="24/", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    Columns("E").Replace What:="25.", Replacement:="25/", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    Columns("E").Replace What:="26.", Replacement:="26/", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    Columns("E").Replace What:="27.", Replacement:="27/", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    Columns("E").Replace What:="28.", Replacement:="28/", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    Columns("E").Replace What:="29.", Replacement:="29/", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    Columns("E").Replace What:="30.", Replacement:="30/", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    Columns("E").Replace What:="31.", Replacement:="31/", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
```

(I know this wouldn't be efficient, but i just want the damn macro to work)

I also tried to change the format of the cell with,

Range("E9:E2905").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"

What i expect is that when i change the cells to a date format the months and days are not swapped.

If there are more info i can provide please tell me.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try Format: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications

Comment: What is your default date format?  mm/dd/yyyy ?

Comment: I already figure it out with thanks to Ron. My default date format is dd/mm (i'm from Argentina).

I did try a simple Format(Range("E9"), "dd/mm/yyyy") and then copying that to another cell, just to see if that would work, and it did, so thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you write, I am guessing that your dates are being imported as Text strings, and not real dates.  You can confirm this by executing the function `ISTEXT(cell_ref)` and seeing if it returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`

If some dates are **real** and others are text, you'll need to correct that earlier in the process -- either in SAP or in the import process.

If you have control over the SAP code, you may be able to export them as real dates, rather than text strings, but I'm not familiar with that process.

However, if they are all text, you can convert them with this macro.

As written, it will convert all dates in column E to your desired format.  It will write the results in the adjacent column so you can compare with the original for debugging purposes, but you can easily change the code to overwrite if you prefer, or even put the results elsewhere.

The code will clear any contents of column F, so be sure to test this on a copy, not the original.

You can also add error checking if you happen to have dot separated strings in column E that are not dates.

**EDIT**: Here is a simpler method than my original code:  *This uses the text-to-columns method which can also be used in native excel.*  As with the original, you can change from writing the results in the adjacent column to overwriting, in this case by removing the several references to `.Offset(0,1)`.

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub convDate()
    Dim WS As Worksheet, R As Range

Set WS = Worksheets("sheet1")
With WS
    Set R = .Range(.Cells(1, "E"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp))
End With

With R 'remove the "offset(0,1) to overwrite"
    .TextToColumns Destination:=.Offset(0, 1), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
         Tab:=False, semicolon:=False, comma:=False, Space:=False, other:=False, _
         fieldinfo:=Array(1, xlDMYFormat)
    .Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.AutoFit
    .Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
End With
End Sub
```

---

**Original Code**

```
Option Explicit
Sub convDates()
    'assumes dates are a string with format of dd.mm.yyyy
'declare variables
  Dim WS As Worksheet, R As Range
  Dim V As Variant, W As Variant, I As Long

Set WS = Worksheets("sheet1") 'alter to suit

'set the Column E range
'read column E into array
With WS
    Set R = .Range(.Cells(1, "E"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp))
    V = R 'this will be a 1-based 2D array
End With

For I = 1 To UBound(V, 1)
    W = Split(V(I, 1), ".")
    If UBound(W) = 2 Then _
        V(I, 1) = DateSerial(W(2), W(1), W(0))
Next I

With R.Offset(columnoffset:=1)
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = V
    .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use Excels ability to post to a range in one go then just copy and paste as values and replace the original location:

```
Sub FixDates()
Columns("F:F").Insert
Range("E1:E8").copy 'Doing this and the next line just in case you have headings you want to keep
Range("F1:F8").Paste
Range("F9:F" & Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=DATE(RIGHT(E1,4),MID(E1,FIND(""."",E1,1)+1,FIND(""."",E1,FIND(""."",E1,1)+1)-FIND(""."",E1,1)-1),LEFT(E1,FIND(""."",E1,1)-1))"
Range("F9:F" & Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy
Range("F9:F" & Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Columns("E:E").Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: You just save my life